# using python unable to read image modified time

Tags: python, image, exif

We are detecting faces from the video. Subsequently we are generating images from every face detected. We need to record the image timestamp.

We observed that the parameter (modified) needs to read from the image properties.

I've tried with the below snippet:

```
import EXIF
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def get_exif(fn):
    ret = {}
    i = Image.open(fn)
    info = i._getexif()
    for tag, value in info.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        ret[decoded] = value
    return ret


photo_path = "test.jpg"
data = get_exif(photo_path)
```

It is returning blank. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Is your image file in the same directory as your script? Otherwise, you should provide the real path or relative path.

Comment: its in the same directory

Comment: What do you mean by „blank“? Does `test.jpg` actually _have_ EXIF data stored?  How did you check this?

Comment: Actually the image is generated from MP4 file. it has only "modified time" it does not have complete EXIF data

Comment: Which library is used (name, version)? What is the error message (if any)? Is the library able to read incomplete metadata? Which metadata are mandatory?

Comment: What do you mean by „modified time“?  Which EXIF tag holds this information? The _DateTime_ tag is understood by `PIL`.  Is `data` really empty? Which program did you use to check that the tag is actually in the file?